# Nested rows in JavaFX-8 TableView

Tags: javafx, javafx-8

How can I implement nested rows (not columns) with JavaFX TableView? Or merge rows in TableView?

Answer (score 2):

There is no API in the current version (1.8.0u40) of JavaFX for that. [ControlsFX](http://fxexperience.com/controlsfx/) has a spreadsheet control that may have the functionality you are looking for.